# Error JSON.parse [Object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

tengo este código el cual envio a un Websocket.

```
 var msg = { 

                        "mensaje": "NUEVO REQ",
                        "titulo":titulo,

                        "data":
                        {
                            "tipo":tipo,
                            "cod_usuario": usuarioFinal ,
                            "cod_requerimiento": idIngresada,
                        }


                    };

                    WS.send(JSON.stringify(msg));

                });
```

y en el websocket lo recibe así

```
  ws.on('message', message => { //Recibe mensaje
    console.log(`Mensaje Recibido => ${JSON.parse(message)}`); //Lo muestra en consola

    wss.broadcast(message);
})
```

el problema es que en la consola me lo muestra así

> Mensaje Recibido => [object Object]

Comment: Entiendo que en la consola te escribe [object Object] pero el `broadcast` lo hace bien?

Comment: Por cierto, `msg` no es un array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al utilizar el literal template: `Mensaje Recibido => ${JSON.parse(message)}` estás tratando `JSON.parse(message)` como una expresión que eventualmente retornará una string o algún valor concatenable a una string;
no obstante, `JSON.parse` te está transformando la string recibida en el **objeto** correspondiente (que es lo que hace y debería hacer...). En ese caso:

```
console.log(`Mensaje Recibido => ${JSON.parse(message)}`);
```

debería ser:

```
console.log(`Mensaje Recibido => `, JSON.parse(message));
```

Incluso no sería necesario usar un literal template para ello.

Comment: Prefecto , gracias era solo un error de sintaxis :)

Answer (score 1):

solo asigna el JSON a una variable antes.

```
const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message);

console.log(`Mensaje Recibido` => parsedMessage);
```